# Chrome extension warning, tutorial for unpacked extension on windows

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

There's this extension popup warning "Disable developer mode extensions" which shows up on every browser start, even on the dev-channel.

This is annoying beyond belief, but what is even worse, is that there is no clear step by step tutorial on how to allow the automatic execution of an unpacked extension via policies, which they say is the only way to remove the popup.

So, is it even possible to remove the popup for unpacked extensions which resides in a directory on the windows desktop?

How do I go about configuring the computer in such a way that the browser won't bug me on every new browser launch?

There is no intention to pack this extension until it has been fully developed and debugged.

Comment: I very much agree with you. I've written to Google at https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2811969?p=ui_remove_non_cws_extensions&rd=1 and pointed them to this StackOverflow question.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it without building your own Chrome or hacking the chrome.dll

Here is one [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30361260/4468645), don't know if it works anymore.